# Dismissing UIAlertController from UIWindow in UIWindow

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIWindow` that I'm using to display a second `UIWindow` whose `rootViewController` is presenting a `UIAlertController`. When I dismiss the `UIAlertController`, the main window is nonresponsive, and I'm not sure why. Here's my implementation:

```
func buttonPressed() {

        var window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add a comment to your post?", message: "You can also tag your friends.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: { (action) -> Void in

            // this isn't working
            window.rootViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            window.removeFromSuperview()



        })

        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

            // do something

        })

        alert.addAction(ok)
        alert.addAction(cancel)
        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({(txtField: UITextField) in
            txtField.placeholder = "What's on your mind?"
            txtField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default
            txtField.autocapitalizationType = .None
        })



        window.rootViewController = UIViewController()
        window.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.addSubview(window)

        self.repostButton.setTitle("Pressed!", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Got it. Just called `window.hidden = true`in the completion handler of cancel. Guess I just overthought it. :)